# Error opening http://example.com/myphpadmin - HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name ip; 
root /var/www/html/public;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}
```

}

ERROR

```
thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php on line 253" while reading response header from upstream, client: MYIP, server: _, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2->
```

2021/03/21 09:00:00 [error] 31206#31206: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PhpMyAdmin\mb_strpos() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:253
Stack trace:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usw0z.png)

Comment: I would suggest you to ask phpmyadmin's support forum for help, as you are asking us to troubleshoot a complex open-source system.

Answer (score 0):

`mb_strpos` is not part of the core PHP package, it's part of the `mbstring` extension

You can install it with the following command:

`sudo apt install php-mbstring`